# How do I not display rows that have an empty value when trying to output a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have this table where there are missing values under the value2 column.

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 |  |
| 1000 |  |
| 1000 | 500 |
| 1000 | 560 |
| 1000 | 560 |

What I would like to do is to display the above table but without the empty rows, therefore the table should look like this

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 500 |
| 1000 | 560 |
| 1000 | 560 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter out those rows using `pandas` indexing: `df[df["Value2"].notna()]`